# How does the Euler Totient Function apply here?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

How many positive integers $< 2013$ are divisible by $2$

Can I somehow use Euler's Totient function to find this?

Comment: That's no necessary. List them. What are the even numbers that are $<2013$? Well, those are $2,4,\ldots,2012$ so the number is $1006$.

Comment: $\frac{2012-2}{2}+1$.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff, what about how many positives integers $< 2013$ that are divisible by $2, 3, 5$ ? Would you use Totient?

Comment: Possibly more interesting challenge: Find the maximum power of $2$ that divides $2013!$ Or the same for any prime $p$.

Answer (score 1):

As your problem is currently stated, you are  asking how many even numbers there are less than $2013$. For integers less than $2013$ that are divisible by $3$,$5$ or a general prime $p$, I would just use the division algorithm to rewrite $2012 = qp+r$ where $q,r \in \Bbb{N} \cup \{0 \}$ and $r<p$. The number you are looking for is $q$.

Comment: ;-) ... with $r<p$

Comment: Thanks @Joffan! That is an important detail :)